# Why does Access VBA prompt me for a Macro when I press F5 or Run Sub?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I found this question [Why does Excel VBA prompt me for a Macro name when I press Run Sub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639581/why-does-excel-vba-prompt-me-for-a-macro-name-when-i-press-run-sub) but the answers don't help me because my sub doesn't have arguments and is not triggered by an event.

I have two subs. One in a Module and one in a Form.

```
Sub ModuleSub()
    MsgBox ("Hello World")    
End Sub


Sub FormSub()
    MsgBox ("Hello World")
End Sub
```

The Module Sub DOES RUN when I press F5, but the Form Sub doesn't. It brings up the Macro dialog. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macros stored in modules **are independent** and can be ran just like that.

However, all the functions/subs stored in Form modules or in Class modules are in fact **the methods of this form/class** and they cannot be ran without instance of this form/class.

---

If you open *Immediate window* (CTRL + G) you can run this code:

```
Call ModuleSub
```

without any issues.

---

This code:

```
Call FormSub
```

will return *Compile error: Sub or function not defined*.

However, if you add the name of form before the name of the function (like below):

```
call Form_FormName.FormSub 'replace FormName with the name of your form.
```

this sub will be also invoked without any issues, since you dynamically create an instance of form and VBA compiler can use its methods.